# Tiny White Space To The Right Of Div In Bootstrap Site

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem where there is a persistent bit of white space to the right of my row in a bootstrap site, despite the fact that I seem to have everything set to full width style (0 margin, container-fluid, etc.).

I started stripping elements off of my site to get it as simple as possible to see what the problem is. I'm now down to just the head content, a container-fluid, and a row, and yet the problem still persists.

```css
html, body, .container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.home {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("../images/background3.jpeg"); 
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Modern Business - Start Bootstrap Template</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pathway+Gothic+One" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row home">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The pic below is what the site looks like. You can see the white space quite clearly (on the right, very small, like 5px or so).

[image: http://i.imgur.com/fI0XqmO.png]

Answer (score 1):

The default margin for the row class is causing this

edit your css for `.home` class like this:

```
.home{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

For any element, It is always a good idea to put `margin:0;padding:0;` the second you start to write its css. You can always add margins and paddings later as they fit but it wont cause you problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin:0`, to your .home class to override bootstrap default margin:

https://jsfiddle.net/yc6p7osk/1/

If you inspect .row - you will notice some default margins there.

Also, you could use another boostrap class for 100% width container, probably.

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body, .container-fluid {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.home {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding-top: 10%;
padding-bottom: 10%;
background-size: cover;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

When you use width and height 100%, the default is to add the borders and such to the width. Add box-sizing: border-box; and your block will be 100% regardless.

More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

HTH.

Comment: PS: Tested with the above; no gap.

Comment: No, box-sizing will not work in this case: See by your self: https://jsfiddle.net/yc6p7osk/2/ Element have two classes - default bootstrap's .row add margins. Btw, box-sizing:border-box is part of bootstrap default CSS... so, no need to add it.

Comment: I see what's up: I'm not loading bootstrap, as that piece of malware will NEVER be on any of our servers. Guess you're right.

Comment: LoL, i have to agree with you. :) It is so bloated, over-used framework these days... which actually (sometimes) cause more problems than it solves... :)

Comment: INtrinsically inaccessible too. So, avoid at all cost unless you like fines. But... getting OT here. :)